# What does “nise tsundere “ mean?

Tags: meaning, words

I was reading the description of a character and they referred to her personality as “nise tsundere".

「偽ツンデレ」

I understand basically what "tsundere" means. The translation came up as fake tsundere. I found a this term on a few sites, but I don't understand the meaning really. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

This may be the first time an answer to a question on this site was "the automatic translation got it right". However, this time the automatic translation did get it right.

`偽` is a fairly common prefix that can be attached to other words to mean a fake version of that thing, although it has slightly broader applications than the English word `fake` and can also mean something like `pseudo`. For example, [偽医療](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quackery) is the word for fake medicine while [偽中国語](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Chinese) is a type of Japanese internet slang that closely resembles Chinese.

While it is hard to know the exact intent of the speaker without more context, `偽ツンデレ` almost certainly refers to someone who appears to be `ツンデレ` but in fact is not. This could imply that the person was intentionally pretending, or not.

Comment: Google translate probably gets two-word or three-word expressions right the majority of the time.